# C# SHA-256 vs SQL Server SHA2

Tags: c#, sql-server, sha

My C# code produces the same hash as the online hash calculator and as my old Basic library, and others:

```
var sha256 = SHA256.Create();
var hashed = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_checksum));
_checksum = BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

For example,

```
"test" -> "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"
```

I have to reproduce the same hash directly from a SQL Server command, if I use

```
SELECT master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA2_256', 'test'), 1, 0)
=> "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"
```

*BUT* if I try to use one of my columns, it produce a different result:

```
SELECT master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA2_256', t.sMANAGER), 1, 0)
FROM EV_AGENCY t
=> "fe520676b1a1d93dabab2319eea03674f3632eaeeb163d1e88244f5eb1de10eb"
```

The column is a `nvarchar`, collation is `French_CI_AI`.

I assumed that I have to cast correctly my column, so I try cast, convert, etc without success.

Can someone help me with that ?

Thank you !

Comment: You have a problem with the `nvarchar`: it is UTF-16. But C#-side you are using UTF8... The easiest thing is to use UTF-16 C#-side, the more complex thing is to convert to UTF8 T-SQL-side.

Comment: If you think the other question isn't similar enough to yours then reply to me and I'll reopen this question.

Comment: xanatos, the UDF did the trick. Amazing, thank you for your *Clairvoyance*